# Adjust a Grid of Photos

Tags: margins, subfloats

I am using the following code snippet to place 11 figures into a 3x4 grid:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{\label{fig:aliev-panfilov-frames}The result of monodomain model
combined with Aliev-Panfilov.}
\subfigure[t=0]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/1}}
\subfigure[t=10]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/50}}
\subfigure[t=20]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/100}}\\
\subfigure[t=30]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/150}}
\subfigure[t=40]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/200}}
\subfigure[t=50]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/250}}\\
\subfigure[t=60]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/300}}
\subfigure[t=70]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/350}}
\subfigure[t=80]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/400}}\\
\subfigure[t=90]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/450}}
\subfigure[t=100]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/501}}
\end{figure}
```

which result in the following figure:

[image: Grid]

As you see, the pictures seem a bit small and there is a lot of white space in the page. How can I reduce the space between the pictures and make the margin smaller to make the pictures look larger? Note that, I don't want to change the margin for all the pages of the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your code, images in the same row are separated only for a blank space, so perhaps your images contain some white space that could be cropped? I don't think it's really a good idea to change the margins for a single page of your document (the layout will then be inconsistent), but if you decide you really want to do it, you can use `\newgeometry` from the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package; to restore the previous layout you then will use `\restoregeometry`. A little schematic example illustrating this:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{hmargin=2.5cm}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{\label{fig:aliev-panfilov-frames}The result of monodomain model
combined with Aliev-Panfilov.}
\subfigure[t=0]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/1}}
\subfigure[t=10]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/50}}
\subfigure[t=20]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/100}}\\
\subfigure[t=30]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/150}}
\subfigure[t=40]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/200}}
\subfigure[t=50]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/250}}\\
\subfigure[t=60]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/300}}
\subfigure[t=70]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/350}}
\subfigure[t=80]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/400}}\\
\subfigure[t=90]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/450}}
\subfigure[t=100]{\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/501}}
\end{figure}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some remarks:

1. I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` to replace the actual images with black rectangles; do *not* use the `\PassOptionsToPackage` line in your actual code.
2. `subfigure` is an obsolete package. You could consider using [subfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

Comment: Mohsen: If the culprit is white space, then the picture can be trimmed using `\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 80mm 20mm 5mm, clip, width=.32\textwidth]{figs/AP/501}`. The numbers x and y lengths to be trimmed from lower left and upper right corners respectively. You can play with these numbers for good results. We can't do it since we do not have your figures. See this website for a tutorial - http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/importing_images.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks Harish. I've already done the trim and it really helps. Even after trimming, there is a small space that can be omitted by negative hspace values like `\hspace{-2mm}`.